# ¿Cómo obtengo la posición X de un control en windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas comunidad, quiero obtener la posición del eje X de un label y asignarlo como el ancho maximo de un textbox qué está a la par, esto para que al hacerlo resizable, no sobrepase el label. Si conocen otra manera de hacer controles resizable, les agradeceré me dejen la info. Por el momento, tengo el siguiente código:

```
private void lblDesdeTxt_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNombreExp.MaximumSize = new Size(lblDesdeTxt.Location.X, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Mencionas `hacer controles resizable` ¿Tienes los controles dentro de un `FlowLayoutPanel` o `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: eeeh ningúno de los 2 ejejeje

Comment: Entonces ¿Cómo estas haciendo que los controles sean resizable? osea en el sentido de que sea como sucede en programación web `Responsive Design`

Comment: Estoy usando la propiedad anchor, la cual los estira con el movimiento de la pantalla.

Comment: Ok comprendo también puedes mirar [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-ZNjvKXBUU) usando `FlowLayoutPanel` o  este otro [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSmjhwU_SWQ) , aunque realmente en `WindowsForms` no hay muchas opciones disponibles para hacer las `aplicaciones responsivas` en cambio en `WPF` si. _Esto es solo en base a lo de ajustar los controles en la pantalla_ **NO** estoy hablando sobre el problema que planteas del ancho del textbox ni nada por el estilo.

Answer (score 0):

En el evento `Resize` del `TextBox`

```
private void TextBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pos_X = label1.Location.X;
        if (textBox1.Width >= pos_X)
        {
            //Aca va lo que pasa si el ancho del textbox no supera la posicion en x del label
        }
        else 
        {
            //Aca va lo que pasa si el ancho del textbox supera la posicion en x del label
        }
    }
```

Espero te halla sido útil.